# How to avoid confusion in comparative sentences

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs

In English when you make a comparison you often use : clause + than + clause.

> He works harder than I do.

Whereas in French, as far as I have seen, with the disclaimer that I know very little, it is usually : clause + que + noun, pronoun etc.

> Il travaille plus dur que moi.

How do you avoid confusion resulting from such a construction?

E.g.: *"Je t'aime plus que lui"* could mean : 
*"I love you more than I love him"* or 
*"I love you more than he loves you"*.

I concede that most real-life cases may not allow such a confusion to arise, but is there  way to explicitly avoid it in writing?

Or in other words, can we say the following in French:

> Je t'aime plus que je l'aime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Je t'aime plus qu'il ne t'aime.

En précisant le sens de l'action au travers du second verbe, on indique quel est le *lui* qui est cité.

> Je t'aime plus que je ne l'aime.

Avec deux verbes il ne peut y avoir confusion, l’ambiguïté est levée.

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce qu'il y a 'ne' avant le second verbe quoique il n'y ait pas de négation?

Comment: @Karnn Pour indiquer une comparaison négative, utilisation explétive Cf  http://atilf.atilf.fr/tlf.htm section III